# Why is running Guard outside of bundler dangerous?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, guard

When I run `bundle exec guard` everything is kosher, but if I try to run `guard` I get this:

```
WARNING: You are using Guard outside of Bundler, this is dangerous and could not work. Using `bundle exec guard` is safer.
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `bundler` [official site](http://gembundler.com/):

> Run an executable that comes with a gem in your bundle
>
> `$ bundle exec rspec spec/models`
>
> In some cases, running executables without bundle exec may work, if
>   the executable happens to be installed in your system and does not
>   pull in any gems that conflict with your bundle.
>
> However, this is unreliable and is the source of considerable pain.
>   Even if it looks like it works, it may not work in the future or on
>   another machine. If you want a way to get a shortcut to gems in your
>   bundle
>
> `$ bundle install --binstubs $ bin/rspec spec/models`
>
> The executables installed into bin are scoped to the bundle and will
>   always work

I'm not sure whether there is anything specific about `guard`, but in general it's a good practice to run all your gems' executables via `bundle exec`. May be they just decided to warn developers that running `guard` without it might cause troubles (e.g. if you have different versions of `guard` in your system and in `Gemfile`).

Comment: Doesn't it go against the idea of bundler to bundle a non-app-specific gem, such as guard? It seems silly to force other developers of the application to install guard if they will not use it. Of course gems like Cucumber and Spork are necessary, as the tests will fail (miserably) if they aren't installed. However, Guard is system-specific, save for the Guardfile (which I always add to the .gitignore file). Each developer has his/her own workflow, and some don't like or use Guard.

Comment: Sorry to revive an old question, but I was also wondering the same thing while following [railstutorial.org - 3.6.1](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages?version=3.2#sec:eliminating_bundle_exec) – I noticed I was getting this warning as well. Is installing and using RVM not a remedy for this problem?

Comment: @waffl, no, installing RVM won't help as it has nothing to do with bundler directly.

Comment: @KL-7 While RVM doesn't have to do with bundler directly, aren't the instructions in the [railstutorial.org - 3.6.1](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages?version=3.2#sec:eliminating_bundle_exec) about combining RVM with bundler so you can avoid the 'bundle exec'? Or am I misunderstanding something? Also on the RVM website: [bundler](http://www.beginrescueend.com/integration/bundler/)

Comment: Immediately after installing guard with bundler/rvm 'which guard' showed an old ruby 1.8 system gem. After `cd`ing out and back into the folder, it used the one from the correct gemset (same as bundle exec). This leads me to believe that using RVM solves this as long as you open a new terminal after installation.